# Layout of web image - Windows Phone

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, layout, web, windows-phone-8

In my app, I need to know BitmapImage's layout (Width and Height). BitmapImage's source is an image on the web.
Can someone help me?
Thanks and excuse me for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Height and Width are accessible respectively by the [`PixelHeight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.pixelheight%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and [`PixelWidth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.pixelwidth%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) properties of your BitmapImage object.

Comment: It display me they're both 0

Comment: Probably you are asking for PixelHeight and PixelWidth before it is loaded. You must wait until it is completely loaded.